# Ideals and injective modules

Tags: modules, ideals, injective-module

Let $I$ be a left ideal of $R$. Assume that there exist element in $I$, which is not a zero divisor. How to prove that for every (left) injective $R$-module $Q$ we have $IQ=Q$ ?

I need only hints.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $a \in IQ$ and $a \not\in Q$ and then work from the element in I which is not a zero divisor.

Comment: If $a\in IQ$ then $a$ must be in $Q$, because $I\subset R$ and $IQ\subset RQ\subset Q$ since $Q$ is $R$-module.